# PHP foreach loop queries once

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I'm trying to automize a process where the inventory balance (MySQL-)database updates accordingly to the items which are removed or added from the inventory. 
I have an array of the items which are going to be added which contains the article number (ean) and the quantity (actually there is also the name of the item which I won't be using). I'm trying to use a foreach loop to iterate the same process - which is adding them to a list of every changes in the inventory - over every item in the array.

```
<?php
//connecting
error_reporting(0);
require 'connect.php';
//the loop
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $temp){
    //setting the variables
    $ean = $temp["EAN"];
    $quantity = $temp["quantity"];

     //the query
    $db->multi_query(   '
    set @EAN= ' . $ean . ';
    set @Changevariable = ' . $quantity . ';
    set @time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    set @IDvariable = (select ID from articles where EAN=@EAN);    
    insert into forandring(ID, altered, dt) values (@IDvariable, @Changevariable, @time);');    
    } ?>
```

This is what the array looks like:

```
Array
(
[cart_item] => Array
    (
        [7350071190043] => Array
            (
                [Name] => James tea Tin - Ginger Twist
                [EAN] => 7350071190043
                [quantity] => 3
            )

        [7350071190425] => Array
            (
                [Name] => James tea Tin - Dream Plavour
                [EAN] => 7350071190425
                [quantity] => 5
            )

        [7350071190074] => Array
            (
                [Name] => James tea Tin - Jodhpur Chai
                [EAN] => 7350071190074
                [quantity] => 10
            )

    )

)
```

This is what the table looks like

[image]

It does successfully loop, but only the first item in the array gets added to the database, for some reason (even though the loop repeats >1 times).
Everything else in the loop is looped except the query. That's basically the problem.

I am fully aware of the fact that the code might be kind of inefficient, but I'm very new to programming.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the values to insert as MySQL _variables_ to your insert statement?

Comment: as you are looping you dont need the multi_query, as for each data the insert query will be executed, try to keep $db->query and loop it inside the foreach